# ToolStripProgressBar doesn't repaint when sleeping immediately afterwards

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, sleep

I have only a little experience with threading in WinForms. I am trying to set a progress bar to 100, sleep for 2 seconds, and then hide the progress bar.

I have:

```
public void ProgressBarTimerStop()
{
    if (!AnyWorkersBusy())
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                ProgressBarTimer.Stop();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Application.DoEvents();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                StatusToolStripProgressBar.Visible = false;
                StatusToolStripProgressBar.Value = StatusToolStripProgressBar.Minimum;
            });
        }
        else
        {
            ProgressBarTimer.Stop();
            StatusToolStripProgressBar.Value = StatusToolStripProgressBar.Maximum;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Application.DoEvents();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            StatusToolStripProgressBar.Visible = false;
            StatusToolStripProgressBar.Value = StatusToolStripProgressBar.Minimum;
        }
    }
}
```

For the current problem I am experiencing InvokeRequired is false.

When I call the line:

```
StatusToolStripProgressBar.Value = StatusToolStripProgressBar.Maximum;
```

my watch window shows the value as set, but the GUI has not updated to reflect this. If I immediately sleep for a full two seconds the GUI does not update before sleeping.

If I call Application.DoEvents() without calling sleep beforehand -- it appears to do nothing.

If I sleep, then call DoEvents -- the GUI updates, and then I go back to sleep. This is correct, but I feel like my code is heinous.

Am I misunderstanding a key concept here?

EDIT: ProgressBarTimerStop is called only through "RunWorkerCompleted" event handlers.

I tried this, but it had no effect:

```
StatusToolStripProgressBar.GetCurrentParent().Refresh();
```

Comment: A progress bar is animated on Aero.  That requires the UI thread to pump messages, it won't animate if you don't.

Comment: Should I spawn a child thread that waits for 2 seconds before invoking in order to set the progress bar's visibility? That's the only other option I see..

Comment: None of this makes much sense, stop calling Sleep() and anything else you are considering to make it look like "I'm working on it" when you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'key concept' that you are missing is that updating the progress bar's value does not immediately tell the progress bar to redraw itself.

When you update the progress bar, the GUI thread repaints the progress bar on the next window repaint. This only happens when the GUI thread becomes free to do so. Normally this happens when the window receives a paint message from the operating system. This should be picked up by `Application.DoEvents`, but it could be that the message isn't queued quickly enough to be picked up by `DoEvents`. You may be able to force it to with a `Refresh` call.

Comment: Unfortunately, ToolStripProgressBar does not inherit from Control. As such, it does not expose the method 'Refresh()'. I just tried progressBar.GetCurrentParent().Refresh(), but this did not have an effect.

Would it be considered 'standard practice' to write the code I have above? I've seen that Application.DoEvents() is a very 'code-smelly' method to use... plus the amount of time to sleep for the first sleep call is dependent on processing speed of the computer, yeah?

Comment: You would probably need to call it on the `ToolStrip`. If that doesn't do it, then I don't think I can help much after that.

Comment: The Sleep will pause for 1 second both times.

Comment: GetCurrentParent() returns the Toolstrip. And yes, understood that sleep will pause for 1 second both times. The amount of time required to queue the message will vary each time ran, though. So I can't set a specific minimum amount of time to sleep while waiting for the message to queue.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Though you may have success with `Thread.Sleep(0)` or `Thread.Yield()`.

Comment: Your last suggestion just made everything SO clear. I have a timer which ticks every 100ms and makes the progress bar increment by 1. I think these messages are still in the queue ahead of my call to set the value to Maximum. Then, depending on the amount of time I sleep, it allows some or all of the messages to be ready for DoEvents. So, if I sleep for 300ms I see the progress bar jump a little, but 1500ms and it fills up all the way. CURIOUS!!

Answer (score 0):

Call `StatusToolStripProgressBar.ProgressBar.Refresh();` on every step. `ProgressBar` property   of `ToolStripProgressBar` is hidden and it may not be shown in intellisense list.